# Does nginx, as I suspect, put "Welcome to Nginx!" when it doesn't know what else to do?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I'm debugging a simple (Docker) proxy server which, so far as I know, doesn't have a "default web site" or anything like that.  I think it's getting `302` responses from upstream but I do not yet know why.  But what *is* interesting is that I'm getting *"Welcome to Nginx!"*  Even though I don't think there is a web-site file that would actually produce it nor any reason to go to such a place.

So ... does nginx sometimes produce that response "on its own?"  If so, it would greatly help my troubleshooting if someone could tell me, "under what circumstances?"  If this is a *clue,* I'd like to understand that clue ...

Answer (score 4):

This is, in fact, the [default](https://www.nginx.com/welcome-to-nginx/) `index.html` for an Nginx webserver. If you spin up a vanilla Nginx container and connect inside of it you can even see these files on the filesystem. For example:

```
$> docker run --name nginx -d nginx
98da5173df23ea4690b9ce8bda87d844775c77609905f76b542115e4babcdcfa

$> docker exec -it nginx sh

$> ls /usr/share/nginx/
html

$> ls /usr/share/nginx/html
50x.html  index.html

$> cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So how does this file get interpreted by Nginx? Well, unless you volume mount in your own `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file into the container the Nginx process is going to use the default one that the original container developers added which references the above `index.html` file. We can track this down too:

```
$> ls /etc/nginx/
conf.d  fastcgi_params  koi-utf  koi-win  mime.types  modules  nginx.conf  scgi_params  uwsgi_params  win-utf

$> cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

So if we look here, one thing sticks out. The very last line in the file says: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`. This means that Nginx should continue to recursively process any configuration information it finds in any `*.conf` files present in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory after it finishes reading this configuration file.

So let's take a look at that directory:

```
$> ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/
default.conf

$> cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

What do we see here? Well, mostly that almost the entire config file is commented out. Let's remove those to make it easier to read and understand.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

We can see here that Nginx is defined, by default by the container developers, to route all traffic on port 80 that it receives to `/usr/share/nginx/html` if it enters on `/` or `/usr/share/nginx/html` if it enters on any other path. As demonstrated in the `STDOUT` produced by `cat` earlier in my post, the contents of these files are what you are seeing in your browser.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need any other questions about this!

Comment: **F-A-N-T-A-S-T-I-C-!!!** Just the kind of detailed response I was hoping to receive.  **Thank you!**  (Now, pardon me while I digest it all.) *(Note that this proxy image does create an `/etc/conf.d/default.conf` but you've just cued me in to look harder.)*

Comment: Edit:  I believe that when you "commented out the comments" you omitted a few lines.  The `error_page` directive is left out and it seems to omit `404` also.

Comment: Glad to know it makes sense! :) 

`/etc/conf.d/default.conf` will always exist. It isn't being created by the image, it exists on the image already. It's just not being referenced because it was previously `included` by the default `/etc/nginx/nginx.con`. Since your `nginx.conf` won't make any reference to include that file, it won't be used.

I updated the answer with respect to your point about missing a line to comment removal. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** thanks to TJ's tremendously useful help.  It turns out that the page was actually being delivered by the `nginx` container that was being proxied, and that the root cause was that the proper `volume` was not being mounted into it.

I traced the problem to the container by attempting to `curl` directly to the container's IP address after specifying `ports 8080:80` to allow me to do so.  I then logged-on to the container and looked around *very* carefully.  Indeed it was as TJ described:  an error was being thrown and the default-screen was produced as a result.

When I corrected the `volume` *(bind point)* specification to expose the correct file, the problem disappeared.

---

Incidentally, I surmise (now) that my original presumption that somehow "Nginx produces this page by default" was incorrect.  It really did produce the page because it had been told to do so.  I just didn't fully understand why.